# What is the best way to get a XML as output from a SQL Server procedure in Delphi?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, delphi, stored-procedures

I need to read in Delphi the output from a SQL Server procedure that returns a `XML` as output (`@MSG1`)

```
PROCEDURE dbo.PROC_ZUND_XML
    (@LOTEPC VARCHAR(10), 
     @MSG1 NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT)
```

I've tried to get this output using a `TFDStoredProc` component as well as a `TFDQuery`, however, it doesn't matter the variable type I use in the parameters configuration in Delphi (`ftWideString`, `ftWideMemo` etc.) it always store just the first 8000 characters of the output. A count statement in the SQL Command section of the Delphi's FireDAC Query Editor shows that the output of the procedure have more than 8000 characters.

So, the problem seems to be occurring internally, when the value is assigned to the variable. Does anybody have an idea about how to fix it? Maybe a different approach to the problem... Thanks in advance.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and Delphi 10.2

Comment: I can replicate the same on SQL Server 2014. The procedure seems to trim the data in some way. Try to check `DATALENGTH` of your `MSG1` parameter right after you assign value to it to see its data length. FireDAC then receives the same data length value from ODBC.

Comment: How are you assigning value to @MSG1?

Comment: The problem is certainly on SQL Server side. Inserting for example `SELECT @MSG1 = CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(4001));` into the body results to the error _"The size (4001) given to the convert specification 'nvarchar' exceeds the maximum allowed for any data type (4000)."_ when executing procedure creation script.

Comment: Performing the following code:

`DECLARE @TEST NVARCHAR(MAX);
  EXEC PROC_ZUND_XML 23494, @TEST OUTPUT
  SELECT LEN (@TEST)`

returns `8007`.

The way I'm assigning the value to the variable is

`SET @MSG1 = (SELECT
DRIVER AS "Driver",
'0' AS "TransactionId",
PART_CODE AS "PartCode",
[...]
FROM [#LOTE_ITENS_ZUND]
FOR XML PATH('QueuedItem'),ROOT('RPOrderGenerator'))`

So, the problem doesn't seem to be in the SQL Server side. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to export this xml file to a specific folder, I advise you to use SQL SERVER itself to export this file to a SHARED NETWORK FOLDER.

With **BCP**, you can generate your XML, and save directly to an XML file, in the directory you want ..

**Some useful tips:**

- If necessary, I recommend using the -w argument to avoid confusion
  with Wrong CHARACTERS (À, É, È, Ó, Ò)

Useful Documentations:
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=171529
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms162802(v=sql.110)
https://sqlsouth.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/export-xml-from-sql-server-using-bcp/